# Regex to exclude everything but what's inside [ ] including line breaks

Tags: regex

I want to clean a text that has some notes in [ ]. I just want to have this notes and nothing else. There's some notes with line breaks, but I want to include that also. So in:

```
    lorem ipsum [foo
    bar] lorem ipsum
```

I want to exclude the lorem ipsum, but keep the [foo bar]. Anyone can tell me how to do it?

Comment: What would you do with mismatched brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\[([\s\S]*?)\]
```

The captured group will have the text between the square brackets.

Comment: This one worked, but I realized I wanted something a little bit different. more like this:
        lorem ipsum
        "foo
        bar"
        [foo
        bar]
        lorem ipsum

Where I would like to select just the 
        "foo
        bar"
        [foo
        bar]

Comment: It didn't work like that, but it worked like this: ("[\s\S]+?"[[\s\S]+?]). Thanks for the help, I'm pretty new at this stuff. One more thing, though: I want to exclude any thing like "foo bar" lorem ipsum [foo bar]. I just need to capture the lines where "foo bar" [foobar] are right next to each other and not when there's anything else in between

Comment: [\s\S]+ matches new line as well. For the second question please make it clearer. Perhaps start a new question topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in many regex flavours:

```
\[[^]]+]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pcre based. The `m` switch is for multi-line mode where `.` matches anything including newlines. I'm sure your regex flavour will have multi-line mode

```
~\[(.*?)\]~m
```